# Remove html tags in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

In my rails app I have database called discussions and it has column called 'question'. In my view I use trix-editor to input question. So it is save with html elements. In my app I have below code line within my notification_worker.rb which I used to send email notifications. This is subject line of my email.

```
subject = "New #{@c["title"]} reply to discussion: #{@d["question"]}"
```

Here @d["question"] print with those html elements. Below is the subject line which I had as output.

[image]

Here subject contains div tags.I want to remove it. How can I do this?

Comment: adding some example would be helpful. like, what is the input and what would be the output.

Comment: BTW, check (`strip_tags`) this: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're doing it inside a `*.rb` file. Here is what you can do:

```
st = "new stark industries <div>new discuss</div>"
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(st)
# output: "new stark industries new discuss"
```

Links:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/ClassMethods/full_sanitizer

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

Answer (score 1):

You should use `raw`

`#{raw(@d["question"])}`